# Child not moving when parent node moves?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have three nodes the world, the player and "the player vision". Both the world and the vision SKShapeNodes and my player uses a custom subclass of SKShapeNode. When I move the world all the player moves with it, however when I move the player the vision node stays fixed in it's position. What could be the reason for this?

This is my player class:

```
class Character : SKShapeNode {
    var vision : SKShapeNode
    var spinning = false

    init(size: CGSize) {
        vision = SKShapeNode()

        // Player Shape
        super.init()
        self.path = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: size).path
        self.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        self.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        self.name = "Player"

        // Player Physics Body
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.frame.size)
        self.physicsBody.restitution = 0
        self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player.toRaw()
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.toRaw() | ColliderType.Player.toRaw() | ColliderType.Enemy.toRaw()

        // Vision Shape
        vision = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 1))
        vision.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()

        // Vision Physics body
        vision.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: vision.frame.size)
        vision.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        vision.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Vision.toRaw()
        vision.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
        vision.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()
        self.addChild(vision)
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm just a hunch: try vision without assigning a physicsbody, not sure if and how SK handles child physicsbodies. It might just cause the vision to separate from its parent because physicsbodies don't normally have parent-child relationships

Comment: you were right, the strange thing is that I tested making the world a physicsbody and it does work. The problem is that I need to implement collission detection for the vision node, do you know of any solution while keeping it as a child of player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your vision node is affect by the physics engine separately from its parent due to its own physicsBody.  The solution is to set the vision node's `position` property to `CGPoint(0, 0)` (or whatever you desire it to be in its parent's coordinate system) in the `didSimulatePhysics` step of the frame.  This will have the result of resetting the vision node to "follow" the parent node at all times.